# Unable to manually reply for PowerShell prompt

Tags: powershell, unzip

I'm trying to unzip some files using PowerShell script. During the script execution I got a prompt. But I'm unable to type anything on the screen. Please let me know for any solution.

Code:

```
C:\Test\unzip.exe D:\Target\20190424_151546*.zip
```

Prompt:

> replace 20190424_151546/COS_Transactions_{0008CC29-7892D-4806-A392-951CF75_20190424121200}.xml?
>   [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:

Comment: it seems possible that the window does not have focus. have you tried clicking in/on that window and then typing your response?

Comment: Please show the actual code you're running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding ECHO y has fixed the issue. ie., it has auto replied y to the prompt:

```
ECHO y | C:\Test\unzip.exe D:\Target\20190424_151546*.zip
```